# GitLab CI: how can I set two dependencies pipelines to run in parallel?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

At the moment, I have a pipeline defined with 4 different stages to build dependencies for my project:

```
stages:
  - dependencies-A
  - dependencies-B
  - dependencies-C
  - dependencies-D
  - build
```

Thus, the jobs in the pipeline now run like this:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> build
```

Actually, B depends on A, and D depends on C. The sub-pipelines `A->B` and `C->D` being independent, I would like to run those two sub-pipelines in parallel, to speed up the build. So, that way:

```
A -> B \
         build
C -> D /
```

Is that possible at all?

Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/directed_acyclic_graph/

Comment: Thanks a lot, @MurliPrajapati!! Looks promising! :)  +1!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using Gitlab version > 12.2, you can use `needs` keyword to create a directed acyclic graph.

In this case your .gitlab-ci.yml shoul look something like this:

Here `depB` will start after `depA` successfully completes. Same goes for `depC` and `depD` stages. 
`build` stage will run after all the other stages are done.

```
stages:
  - dependencies-A-C
  - dependencies-B-D
  - build

depA:
  stage: dependencies-A-C

depB:
  stage: dependencies-B-D
  needs: ["depA"]

depC:
  stage: dependencies-A-C

depD:
  stage: ependencies-B-D
  needs: ["depC"]

build:
  stage: build
```

Find more in docs:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/directed_acyclic_graph/

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#needs

Comment: Thanks a lot, @MurliPrjapati! However, from what I read on the docs in the second link you provided, shouldn't be the jobs in the same stage? Also, from what I read, I think `stages:` will not be needed anymore, when using `needs:`. Isn't it?

Comment: Yeah. Valid point. Is it possible for you to put A and C in same stage? `stages` are  required AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, provided that B is built after A and D after C. Thus, the two sub-pipelines `A->B` and `C->D` can be built in parallel in the same stage. Then, the stage `build` will need all of them being built.

Comment: @rmbianchi Updated the yml in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @MurliPrajapati! :) Approved!

Comment: As a side note: `needs:` allows to run a job out of order (depending on how you configure it), but also has a side effect of not downloading any artifact from previous stages!!

Answer (score 2):

Not only can you use needs, as detailed in Murli's answer, but with [GitLab 13.12](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/05/22/gitlab-13-12-released/#show-job-dependencies-in-the-pipeline-graph) (May 2021), you can *see* those pipelines, and visually confirm they will run in parallel.

> ### Show job dependencies in the pipeline graph
>
> The full pipeline graph provides a visual representation of all the jobs in your CI/CD pipeline, grouped by stage.
> This visualization helps you track the progress of your jobs and sets expectations for the order in which jobs will execute.
>
> The introduction of the [`needs` keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#needs) let you create a directed acyclic graph that lets jobs start running earlier than they would if they were configured solely by stage.
>
> However, this creates ambiguity when looking at the pipeline graph, as its harder to tell in what order you could expect jobs to run.
>
> In this release, you now have the ability to view pipelines by job dependencies when the job order reflects the `needs:` relationships between jobs.
>
> We’ve also added links between jobs to see exactly which jobs need to complete before a particular job can start. It will be much easier for you to track and understand job dependencies and expected run order when using the `needs:` keyword.
>
> [image: dependencies in the pipeline graph]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/#view-job-dependencies-in-the-pipeline-graph) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/4509).

---

And [GitLab 16.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/08/22/gitlab-16-3-released/#use-the-needs-keyword-with-parallel-jobs) (August 2023) adds:

> ### Use the needs keyword with parallel jobs
>
> The `needs` keyword is used to define dependency relationships between jobs. You can use the keyword to configure jobs to be dependent on specific earlier jobs instead of following stage ordering. When the dependent jobs complete, the job can start immediately, speeding up your pipeline.
>
> Previously, it was impossible to use the `needs` keyword to set [parallel matrix](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#parallelmatrix) jobs as dependent, but in this release, we have enabled the ability to use `needs` with parallel matrix jobs too.
>
> You can now define a flexible dependency relationship to parallel matrix jobs, which can help speed up your pipeline even more! The earlier your jobs can start, the earlier your pipeline can finish!
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_3/needs.png -- Use the needs keyword with parallel jobs]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#needsparallelmatrix) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/254821).